# Gatsby deploy on Github pages is missing files, but locally look good

Tags: gatsby, github-pages

My site built with gatsby: https://github.com/GiorgioRemindme/giorgio-martini doesnt look fine on the deploy: https://giorgioremindme.github.io/giorgio-martini/

If you see the console, some files are failing with 404s.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Also, If I go to the route `/code` by clicking on the menu, it says no gihub pages are hosted there.

Any ideas whats the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you haven't configured the path prefixing (`pathPrefix`).

In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: "/giorgio-martini",
}
```

And your scripts in the `package.json` should look like something like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"
  }
}
```

For a curated guide, check Gatsby's tutorial about [How Gatsby Works with GitHub Pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/).

By the way, in your repository, you've uploaded the whole content of the `/public` folder (autogenerated) but not the source code so there's nothing to check there.

In addition, check the [`withPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/#add-the-path-prefix-to-paths-using-withprefix) helper if you are creating manual paths.